# checking jquery.cookie values

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I'm creating a to-do-list web app, which sets each to-do as a cookie. I'm trying to loop through jQuery.cookie values to separate out my cookies into 'to-do' and 'done'.

I'm working with this code which at the moment gets all of the cookies, if the key is numeric then it will append the items to my `tbody`

```
var obj = $.cookie();

// add each one to the list!
$.each( obj, function( key, value ){

    if ( $.isNumeric(key) ) {

        // display the table
        $('.grid-100').animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, 300);

        // hide the intro page
        $('.introduction').hide();

        if( value.indexOf('class="done green"') ) {
            // append to tfoot                  
            $('tfoot').append(value);
        } else {
            // append to tbody                  
            $('tbody').append(value);
        }


    } else {

        // do nothing.

    }

});
```

However this doesn't work, all of my to-do's get appended to `tfoot` even if they don't have an `indexOf` `class="done green`.

Comment: `value.indexOf('class="done green"') !== -1`

Answer (score 3):

`indexOf` returns `-1` if the item is not found, which is a truthy value, so you need to check whether the index is greater than -1 to test whether the item is found in the string.

```
if( value.indexOf('class="done green"') >= 0 ) {
```